# find sample for collection of samples

Tags: means

i have following problem,

To estimate the average alcohol consumption of UCSD students, we take three random samples of 40, 45 and 50 students respectively, and their sample means turn out to be 3.15, 3.20 and 2.76 pints per week respectively. What is the sample mean of the collection of all three samples?

i tired following answer but got wrong feedback, what wrong i did?

[40(3.15) + 45(3.20) + 50(2.76)] / (40 + 45 + 50) pints/week

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me

Comment: answer should be 408/135=3.02, but i am getting wrong feedback?!

Comment: now i got correct feedback, i had to answer with one more precision, 3.022